# Find the equation of a plane containing two given points and having a given distance to a third point

Tags: 3d

This problem is part of examination preparation material for second mid-semester test of 12-th grade in my school:

In the 3D space Oxyz, given 3 points $A(1,0,0)$, $B(0,-2,3)$, $C(1,1,1)$. Let $(P)$ be the plane containing $A$, $B$ such that the distance from $C$ to the plane $(P)$ is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. The equation of the plane $(P)$ is:

- A. $2x + 3y + z - 1 = 0$ or $3x + y + 7z + 6 = 0$
- B. $x + y + z - 1 = 0$ or $-2x +37y+17z+13=0$
- C. $x + y +2z - 1 = 0$ or $-2x +3y+7z+23=0$
- D. $x + y + z - 1 = 0$ or $-23x+37y+17z+23=0$

This is a multiple choice question. However, we're still expected to provide some work...

It's not quite important, as it is not part of the mandatory homework section. But I still find it quite interesting, somehow.

So far, the best thing I've got is in Geogebra using some translation and rotations.

As on paper, I don't know where to even start... Surely I can't just tell my teacher "so we rotate this segment $sin^{-1}{(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}} \div |Vector(A,D)|)$ where D is the image of C on plane from A and normal vector AB". Also, I don't know how Geogebra's `Rotate(Object, Angle, PointOfOrigin, Axis)` work.

Any suggestion to an alternative approach to this problem would be appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)). I recommend that you edit your post. (1) You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? (2) Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Comment: “*However, we're still expected to provide some work...*” Golden words!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the equation of the plane be $a x + b y + c z = d $

Since $A$ and $B$ lie on the plane, then

$ a = d $

$ -2 b + 3 c = d $

Further the distance of the plane from $C$ is $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} $.  Therefore,

$ \left( \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^2 = \dfrac{ (a + b + c - d)^2} {a^2 + b^2 + c^2} $

Solving the first two equations, gives

$ a = d = 2t $ , where $t \in \mathbb{R} $

$ c = 2s $, where $ s \in \mathbb{R} $

$ b = 3 s - t  $

Substituting this into the third equation,

$ \dfrac{4}{3} = \dfrac{ (5 s - t)^2 }{ 4 t^2 + (3 s - t)^2 + 4 s^2 } $

so that,

$ 16 t^2 + 4 ( 9 s^2 - 6 s t + t^2 ) + 16 s^2 = 3 ( 25 s^2 + t^2 - 10 t s ) $

And finally,

$ 17 t^2 - 23 s^2 + 6 t s = 0 $

Take $ s = 1 $, then

$ 17 t^2 + 6 t - 23 = 0 $

Factor,

$(17 t + 23) (t - 1) = 0$

whose roots are

$ t =1 $ and $ t = - \dfrac{23}{17} $

For $ t = 1 $ we get

$ a = d = 2 , c = 2 , b = 2 $

So that the equation is $ x + y + z = 1 $

And for $ t = -\dfrac{23}{17}$, modify $s$ to $17$ , then $t = -23 $, and we will have,

$ a = d = -46 , c = 34 , b = 3(17) + 23 = 74 $

Dividing through by $2$, the equation is

$  - 23 x + 37 y + 17 z = -23 $

Comment: Thank you. But can you clarify a bit at the "Solving the first two equations, gives a = d = 2t where t ∈ R" please? I assume the 2 equations are "a = d" and "-2b + 3c = d".

Comment: The two equations are in the 4 variables $a,b,c,d$ and that's their solution in terms of the free parameters $t$ and $s$

Answer (score 2):

Finding a line in $R^{3}$ through A and B is simple enough. The problem that then arises is that since point C is not on the plane, it is not simply a case of finding two vectors in the plane etc.

I would suggest elimination of wrong answers is the approach intended by the way the question is written.

Option A: the plane $2x+3y+z-1=0$ does not go through point A so we can eliminate this option.

Option B: both planes contain points A and B and so we need to check the distance from each to the point C. The plane $-2x+37y+17z+13=0$ is not the required distance from C (the first plane in option B is the required distance though).

Option C: The plane $-2x+3y+7z+23=0$ is not the required distance from C.

So by elimination, it must be D.

Checking that points A and B are in both planes and both are the required distance from C is not too difficult to show.

Comment: Since the requirements identify two planes, I would interpret the answer as saying "these are the two planes".  This is the approach that occurred to me, but if I specify "you must show your work" in a class, I don't usually count checking the answer as showing work.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I am scarce in English language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by rotation of the normal vector of the plane, then first find the vector

$ V = B - A = (0, -2, 3) - (1, 0,0) = (-1, -2, 3) $

Create two orthogonal unit vectors to $V$, these are arbitrary, but an easy choice is

$ U_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (2, -1, 0) $

$U_2 = \dfrac{ V \times U_1}{\| V \times U_1 \| }$

Now $ V \times U_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} ( 3 , 6 , 5 ) $

So that

$ U_2 = \dfrac{ (3, 6, 5)}{ \sqrt{70}} $

Now the equation of the plane is a function of one parameter only $\theta$

The equation is

$ N \cdot ( r - A )  = 0 $

where $N = \cos \theta \ U_1 + \sin \theta \ U_2 $

Since $N$ is a unit vector, the distance between $C$ and the plane as given in this equation is $| N \cdot (C - A) | $.  And we have $C - A = (0, 1, 1) $

Therefore, we require that

$ | \cos \theta (U_1 \cdot (C - A) ) + \sin \theta (U_2 \cdot (C - A) | = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} $

Now $U_1 \cdot (C - A) = - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $

and $U_2 \cdot (C - A) = \dfrac{11}{\sqrt{70}} $

We already know that there are only two solutions, so we can drop the absolute value operation.  Hence, the equation becomes

$ - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \cos \theta + \dfrac{11}{\sqrt{70}} \sin \theta = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} $

The solutions of this trigonometric equation in radians are

$ \theta_1 = 1.30963916 $

and

$ \theta_2 = 2.487700856 $

The corresponding normal vector $N$ is

With $\theta_1$:

$ N = \langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \rangle $

and $ d = N \cdot A = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

So that, after scaling by $\sqrt{3}$ the equation becomes:

$ x + y + z = 1 $

With $\theta_2$, we get:

$ N = \langle -0.491816896 , 0.791183702, 0.363516836 \rangle $

and $ d = N \cdot A = -0.491816896 $

So that after scaling, we get

$ -23 x + 37 y + 17 z = -23 $

Comment: Thanks a lot for this second solution! But I'm quite confused about the plane equation "N (r - A)". What is `r`? I did get the desired result by writing the normal plane equation that goes through A though.

Comment: Sorry.  $r=(x,y,z)$